# Slideshow with multiple images needing a previous image button.

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I created an array of images. I want to be able to create a previous image button but am having trouble. This is my previous button code:

```
-(IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender
{
    int ptr = 0;

    if (ptr <= 5)
    { 
         ptr--;
         ptr = 5;
         [imageView setImage:[images objectAtIndex:ptr]];
    }

    NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Americans.png",@"Approach.png",@"Arianny.png",@"Atoms.png",@"Australia.png",@"Average.png",nil];

    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:ptr]]];
}
```

Comment: What should be the previous image for 1? Is it 5 ? You implemented your logic in very long way.

Comment: I was using the numbers as an example. I have an array of images set up to display randomly ( in no given order). I want this button to be able to display the previous image that was currently shown (going back in a sense)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it the code you show (changeImage) is supposed to be the code that you want to use for previous image, or it's just code you already have intended for some other purpose to change the image. But this code has a few things wrong with it.

The scope for the variable ptr is only within the method block, so it will always get set to 0, then decremented, then set to 5. So you will always end up showing the image at index 5 when the changImage method executes. Also, if you have two methods that refer to an array of images, that array will have to be an ivar, which you can set up in your initialization code.

From what I can tell in your question, one thing you want to do is change the image to another random image from the range of images in the array `images`. The second thing you want to do is show the image that was shown previously.

So you need two methods. One method generates a random index over the range of valid indexes of the image array. The other method shows the image that was shown previously.

So you will need to set up an ivar that holds the index of the last image shown. The first method will have to replace the value in that ivar immediately before generating a new random index. The second (showPrevious) method will use the value of this 'lastIndex' ivar to select the index you want to go back two.

If you want to go back more than one step of previous image, and the images indexes are randomly generated, then you will need an array to remember the sequence of the random indexes that were generated. That a little more complicated, and based on the code you have shown so far for your question, you show probably keep it simple at first, and just do one step backward. Also, you don't show how you generate random indexes. You need to write that code if you haven't already done it.

Comment: can u supply some sort of code of how i would go to the previous images?, because that is what i am having trouble doing.